# ASP.NET MVC - How to Decode special characters(&quot;) with text in javascript and html

Tags: javascript, html, regex, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

i am using kendo Listview.Inside the template there are some texts with encoded characters such as &quote ;Test Title1&quote

I used encoded() function in javascript to decode special characters and using

```
 @HttpUtility.HtmlDecode
```

on view to decode special characters.But if it is contains text with special characters, these functions don't work.

I mean, if a data contains like  (&quote ;Test Title1&quote) I dont know how to decode.I would like the get output from this value is  "Test Title"

This is the view

```
   <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">
...
....
@HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("#:Title#")
 <a   href="javascript:openNewsPopup(unescape('#:Title#'),'#:Summary#','#:Content#','#:ImageURL#','#:AddTime#','#:AddDate#','#:AddYear#','#:SubmitedBy#')" class="btn pull-right">
<span style="font-weight:normal" rel="tooltip" title="Read more about the announcement">Read More</span></a>
```